# ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call

Tags: java, oracle

I want call a procedure from my Java code to delete from database. Below is my Java code and exception

```
String procedureCall = "{call NEW_PORTING_PRC.delete_album_metadata(?)}";
                        CallableStatement cal = conn.prepareCall(procedureCall);
                        cal.setString(1, catId);
                        cal.registerOutParameter(2, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
                        cal.execute();
```

Exception is:

```
ERROR ["http-bio-8080"-exec-9] (Content_005fDelete_jsp.java:45) - [15-05-15 14:16:01,912] -  
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DELETE_ALBUM_METADATA'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: add another `place holder` in in your **procedureCall** as you are supplying two arguments to it.

Comment: I remove the registerOutParameter() call. Now I am having only one argument but still getting error.

Comment: How many parameters do actually your procedure needs? What is your updated exception?

Comment: I have created procedure with custom type in parameter(varchar_tab as varchar2). How to set the custom type parameter in jdbc?

Comment: create or replace TYPE "VARCHAR_TAB"                                                                         
is
table of varchar2(500);

Answer (score 2):

you are passing one parameter to the `NEW_PORTING_PRC.delete_album_metadata` procedure and it's expecting a different number of parameters

or

you are passing a varchar where it is expecting a number, date etc

Comment: procedure delete_album_metadata
  (
   p_catalog_tab in varchar_tab
  );

Comment: Above is my procedure in database

Comment: the procedure seems to be expecting a varchar_tab, which i believe is an array (i haven't used them myself) so sending a varchar to it might be the cause of the problem.